# How to make curl call to href with javascript

Tags: javascript, http, curl

Kindly clarify below doubt wrt cURL to href with javascript

After making cURL call to http page , I get below 2 elements.

```
      <a href="javascript:MFFundHolding('2')">Previous</a>

     <a href="javascript:MFFundHolding('4')">Next</a>
```

Now I want to make curl call to these to get subsequent data , how to do it ?

Comment: why don't you use AJAX? Why do you need cURL?

Comment: cURL alone cannot do this for you. You need to parse the HTML to discover JavaScript code embedded in the HTML itself, JavaScript accessed by remote URLs (and then use cURL to download them), etc and then parse the JavaScript to discover what the `MMFundHolding()` function does, and if it refers to remote URLs then download them, etc. A LOT of work not directly related to cURL itself. It is strictly a resource transfer library, not a script execution environment. It cannot replicate all of the complex that a web browser normally handles.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have requirement similar to http://www.hdfcsec.com/MutualFund/MFFundHolding.aspx?CoCode=301 and later go through each of Showing page 1 of 9 and get rows count. I was thinking to get JSON response and parse in Java. can you please suggest any better way to do these operations ?

Comment: @vikramvi scraping data from dynamically generated HTML is one of worst ways to go. If you can get the data in XML or JSON instead, that is a lot better.